# Configure Gitlab to fetch MR branch instead of commit hash

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CI configuration for merge requests like this:

```
# build artifacts and run tests
build-and-test:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean verify
  only:
    - master
    - merge_requests
```

When I push to a MR, gitlab checks out a specific commit, instead of the branch being used in the MR. This makes my gitver configuration ignore the branch name.

Can I make Gitlab fetch the branch instead of the commit? Every MR has a specific branch, right?

Answer (score 0):

MRs are actually built in a detached commit, it seems like it's an implementation detail of gitlab. Maybe it's made to protect from accidental pushes?

If you have `git` on you machine or build container, you can manually checkout to `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` variable or to use it somehow in your gitver.

`$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` also seems to be set to source branch name in my tests, it might be a bit more convenient in case of having single job for both master and MR branches.

Edit: example pipeline for merge checks only:

```yaml
build-and-test:
  stage: build
  script:
    - git checkout $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean verify
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your suggestion. I'm using Gitlab as a git repo and using it's CI feature. Both have git, but the checkout is automatically done by the pipeline with the configuration I shared. Can you details a bit more your suggestion?

Comment: This didn't work `error: pathspec 'mr_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.`. I'm using the configuration setting to fetch only the last 50 commits, and according to git documentation `git clone --depth`, `Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. Implies --single-branch`, which means other branches are not available. I looked around, but I don't know how to fix it.